# Passing and reading attributes in new threads (pthreads)

Tags: php, pthreads

I have class Program which uses class Model. Now I need to run Program in multiple threads, but it doesn't work correctly. My code is:

```
$connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=x', 'y', 'z');

class Model {
    public $connection;
    public function setConnection(PDO $connection) {
        $this->connection = $connection;
        //echo get_class($this->connection)." | setConnection<br />\n"; //returns PDO
    }
}

class Program {
    public $model;
    public function setModel(Model $model) {
        $this->model = $model;
    }
    public function run() {
        echo get_class($this->model->connection)." | run<br />\n";
    }
}

class ProgramThread extends Thread {
    public $i;
    public $program;

    public function __construct($i, Program $program, PDO $connection)
    {
        $this->i = $i;
        $this->program = $program;
        $this->program->model->setConnection($connection);
        echo get_class($this->program->model->connection)." | __construct<br />\n";
    } 

    public function run()
    {
        $this->program->run();
    }
}
//
$program = new Program();
$model = new Model;
$program->setModel($model);
```

Now I run it in multiple threads:

```
$threads = [];
foreach (range(1, 1) as $i) { //only 1 thread for example
    $threads[$i] = new ProgramThread($i, clone $program, clone $connection);
    $threads[$i]->start();
}
```

It returns wrong class names Program and ProgramThread instead of expected PDO.

```
Program | run
ProgramThread | __construct
```

When I delete "extends Thread" from the first code and run:

```
$pt = new ProgramThread(1, clone $program, clone $connection);
$pt->run();
```

It returns the correct result:

```
PDO | __construct
PDO | run
```

Where is the problem?

---

**Here is simpler example with the same output:**

```
class Program {
    public $connection;
    public function run() {
        echo get_class($this->connection)." | run<br />\n";
    }
}
class Connection { //unserializable class
}
class ProgramThread extends Thread { //try deleting  "extends Thread"
    public $program;
    public function __construct(Program $program, Connection $connection)
    {
        $this->program = $program;
        $this->program->connection = $connection;
        echo get_class($this->program->connection)." | __construct<br />\n";
    } 

    public function run()
    {
        $this->program->run();
    }
}

$connection = new Connection();
$program = new Program;

$pt = new ProgramThread(clone $program, clone $connection);
$pt->run();
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues with what you are trying to do:

- PDO is an object which relies on resources to function.
- The properties of a threaded object don't work like other objects.

Resources are officially unsupported, what you want to do is use a PDO object for each thread, passing only connection parameters into a thread. Even if a driver by chance happened to work with pthreads, it wouldn't be safe to use it, you must create a connection per thread.

```
<?php
class Program {
    public function run() {
        echo get_class($this->connection)." | run<br />\n";
    }
}

class Connection {}

class ProgramThread extends Thread {

    public function __construct(Program $program, Connection $connection)
    {
        $program->connection = $connection;

        $this->program = $program;

        echo get_class($this->program->connection)." | __construct<br />\n";
    } 

    public function run()
    {
        $this->program->run();
    }
}

$connection = new Connection();
$program = new Program;

$pt = new ProgramThread(clone $program, clone $connection);
$pt->run();
```

Notice that this gives the output you expected because the connection is set before serializing the object for storage.

This is still horrible code and it won't behave as you expect when you swap example objects for PDO.

```
<?php
class PDOWorker extends Worker {

    public function __construct(array $config) {
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    public function run() {
        self::$connection = 
            new PDO(...$this->config);
    }

    private $config;

    public static $connection;
}

$pool = new Pool(4, PDOWorker::class, [["sqlite:example.db"]]);

while (@$i++<10) $pool->submit(new class extends Collectable {
    public function run() {
        if (PDOWorker::$connection) {
            printf("Got connection from %s in Thread #%lu\n",
                get_class($this->worker),
                Thread::getCurrentThreadId());
        }

    }
});

$pool->shutdown();
?>
```

Will output something like:

```
Got connection from PDOWorker in Thread #140458223204096
Got connection from PDOWorker in Thread #140458210621184
Got connection from PDOWorker in Thread #140458234603264
Got connection from PDOWorker in Thread #140458223204096
Got connection from PDOWorker in Thread #140458223204096
Got connection from PDOWorker in Thread #140458234603264
Got connection from PDOWorker in Thread #140458210621184
Got connection from PDOWorker in Thread #140458198038272
Got connection from PDOWorker in Thread #140458198038272
```

*PHP7 code, because the world is moving on ... you can extrapolate backwards if you wish to see PHP5 code ...*

Notice how the PDO object is stored in a static class member, these are treated as thread-local by pthreads and are never serialized. So each Thread has it's own connection and everything behaves as expected, and you are using the driver as intended.

Comment: I've replaced PDO by Nette\Database (db layer) in run(), now I am getting strange errors. Autoloading doesn't work - I've solved it by including all parts. Another error is here [link](https://api.nette.org/2.3.5/source-Database.Helpers.php.html#171) - self::$typePatterns is NULL, but Nette\DB works perfectly outside of threads.

It may be better to start script in multiple processes or use another language.